# Confusion about retrieving Views from ListView

Tags: android, listview, view, colors, android-arrayadapter

I was trying to create a simple `ListView` in an Android app and change the background color of the views.

I succeeded by simply overwriting the `getView()` method of the defined `ArrayAdapter` class and changing it inside there.

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Categories) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
    View view = super.getView(pos, v, vg);

    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        break;
      case 1:
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    return view;
  }
};
```

However, if I delete the switch-statement and use it outside this function with the returned view, the colors don't update. By that I mean something like this: (`lv` is my `ListView`)

```java
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
  View V = (View) lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, lv);

  switch (i) {
    case 0:
      V.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      break;
    case 1:
      V.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

It does return a reference to the view, so why does it not work that way?

Comment: Can you post the code for this: `delete the switch-statement and use it outside this function with the returned view`? I'm not sure that I understand what you did there.

Comment: I edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: You have this code inside `onCreate`? Also, do you receive any exception in the 2nd case?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change something call:

```
ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Anyways, this is not the fine british way to do this, but I guess every solution is a solution ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sadly this did not fix it

Comment: This is partially true. If you change the data from the `adapter` you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` to reflect those changes on your screen. However, if you have a reference to the view, you can change the way it is displayed without calling that.

Comment: In the original post, I tried both arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and ((ArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); seperately after the switch statement.

Comment: As you're passing `null` as your convertView you will have to inflate your view first.

Comment: `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. Once I created a Colorful List. Here I am just copying my codes.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private final ArrayList<String> dataSet;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView mTextView;
        final CardView cardView;
        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
            cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_container);
        }
    }

    public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
        dataSet = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(dataSet.get(position));
        switch (position%11){
            case 0: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFB71C1C);
                break;
            case 1: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF880E4F);
                break;
            case 2: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF4A148C);
                break;
            case 3: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF311B92);
                break;
            case 4: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF1A237E);
                break;
            case 5: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF01579B);
                break;
            case 6: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF004D40);
                break;
            case 7: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF1B5E20);
                break;
            case 8: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF33691E);
                break;
            case 9: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF827717);
                break;
            case 10: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFE65100);
                break;
            default: holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFBF360C);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use interface:
Define an interface in YourAdapter.class:

```
    public interface OnColorEvent{
     void change(View v,int position)
 }
```

Set the listener in YourAdapter.class:

```
private OnColorEvent e;
public void setOnColorEvent(OnColorEvent e)
{
this.e=e;
}
```

In your getView() method:

```
    @Override
      public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
        View view = super.getView(pos, v, vg);
    if(null!=e)
    {
    e.change(v,pos);
    }
    }
In YourActivity.class:
listview.setOnColorEvent(new OnColorEvent{
@Overide
public void change(View v,int position)
{
switch (position) {
    case 0:
      V.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      break;
    case 1:
      V.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
});
```